# How do I root Sky Pad8 Android tablet?

Tags: rooting

I have a Sky Pad8 Android tablet, and I really want to root it, but I have no idea how.

How do I root Sky Pad8 Android tablet?

Comment: Hi Joshua, have you tried googling.  If you have, you should mention it and tell us the result.

Comment: The manufacturer doesn't seem to be reliable. They claim that the skypad 8 has `Memory: 32GB RAM + 3GB` which is total nonsense, may be 32GB flash + 3GB RAM.